# How to use Scanner to extract integers from {int:int}?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have to read integers from stdin, it comes in following format:

```
{4:11},{23:29},{1:7}...
```

I tried to use scanner delimiter, but I think it has problem with the `first '{'`

```
Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\D");
while (scanner.hasNext()){
  int x = scanner.nextInt();
  int y = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Algorithm.main(Algorithm.java:63)
```

Comment: That's too simplistic an attempt, and I think that with a little more effort and change of your code, you will likely find your own solution. Don't give up -- it's there for you

Comment: Break the problem down by figuring out first how to isolate each `{...}` pair. Then figure out how to parse the ints out of each pair.

Comment: Just using \\D+ would solve the problem. But of source it won't validate that the input indeed has that format.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying a delimiter pattern with the following

```
    scanner.userDelimiter("\\D"); // This \\D is pattern which will be matched.
```

You need to specify the pattern it like following:

```
    scanner.userDelimiter("\\D+") // With + keyword you are saying that it can be 1 or more.
```

Latest working code should look like following:

```
    Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\D+");
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        int y = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("x: " + x);
        System.out.println("y: " + y);
    }
```

The other example is explicitly parsing the string with regex which you may not needed to if you only looking for delimiter pattern matching.

*Note: Since you getting with nextInt(), and not validating the input so if there is invalid input(different input does not contain int) then you will get exception*

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to extract continuous sequences of digits, regardless of the delimiter. You can read input line by line and parse with a `\d+` regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
  }
}
```